# Thermal rader plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am searching thermal weather API for my word_press but i cant get properly.
i want to place thermal map in to my site .
can you please tell me some free API sites to me.
if you have any sites like that please send me that link to me

Answer (score 0):

a few years ago i had to write an app with weather data and the only useful free api (in europe) seemed to come from http://om.yr.no/verdata/free-weather-data/ (a norwegian weather serverice).

the part with xml for different cities was easy to understand but as i don't speak any norwegian i can't tell you if there is something like ready to use thermal maps.